# Javascript Error /[qwertyuiopasdfghjklzx-cvbnm?.//:&#!]/: Range out of order in character class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So when i type it into the console this error pointing to `/[qwertyuiopasdfghjklzx-cvbnm?.//:&#!]/: Range out of order in character class`  . I tried pressing i and it would come up with the same thing. This is a script for https://web.roblox.com. I'm using the `replace()` on a string and that where the error is.

```
/*
    Version 0.1
    Press i to get id
    Please read the settings
    */
    //Settings
    //Welcome Message
    var welcomemsg = "Off";//Write On or Off
    //Functions
    function welcome()
    {
    if (welcomemsg == "On") {
        window.alert("Welcome id getter loaded press i when on an id page to get item id")
    }
    else if (welcomemsg == "Off") {
        console.log("Welcome id getter loaded press i when on an id page to get item id")
    }
    }
    (function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js'); document.body.appendChild(script);}());
    window.onload = function() {
    load()
    };
    function load()
    {
     $( "body" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
       if (event.type === "keydown" && event.which === 73){
       get();
       }

      $( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " +  event.which );

    });
    }
    function get()
    {
    var id = window.location.href.split("=").pop().replace(/[qwertyuiopasdfghjklzx-cvbnm?.//:&#!"]/g, "")
    if (id == "") {
        alert("Your not into an profile, model ,gear page or place!")
    }
    else {
    window.prompt("Id:", id)
    }
    }
    //Running functions
    welcome()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a "-" character in there, and "x-c" is interpreted as a range (which is, for obvious reasons, invalid). Try escaping the - with a backslash ().